# How do i get Binary Tree array from Skit-learn DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

Hence , I have this code of project.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris()
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

I want to get the **Binary tree formatted array** from the `clf` variable , so that I can traverse the tree my own. How this is possible ?

Answer (score 2):

The [tree_](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) attribute will allow you to access the underlying tree structure:

```
t = clf.tree_
```

However, the information that you can access is limited as `tree_` is an instance of a Cython class [Tree](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f65d144e3966113d3daec836e443c6d7a5b/sklearn/tree/_tree.pxd).

That last link shows a Cython header (similar to .h). Attributes and methods starting with `def` or `cpdef` are accessible from python whereas `cdef` aren't.

The .pyx file (equivalent to a cpp) shows [another public attributes](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f65d144e3966113d3daec836e443c6d7a5b/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx) at the end of the file that might interest you:

```
feature : array of int, shape [node_count]
    feature[i] holds the feature to split on, for the internal node i.
threshold : array of double, shape [node_count]
    threshold[i] holds the threshold for the internal node i.
value : array of double, shape [node_count, n_outputs, max_n_classes]
    Contains the constant prediction value of each node.
impurity : array of double, shape [node_count]
    impurity[i] holds the impurity (i.e., the value of the splitting
    criterion) at node i.
```

Thus, `t.feature`, `t.threshold` and `t.value` should fit your needs here.

To properly trasverse the tree `Tree` also exposes `children_left` and `children_right` in a similar interface than above. E.g. at a given node `n` its childrens are:

```
left = t.children_left[n]
right = t.children_right[n]
```

NOTE: I believe those arrays returned are *views* of the underlying numpy arrays, thus you can inspect or modify them in place, but you wont be able to add new nodes (grow the tree further) externally.

Answer (score 0):

use graphviz to display the decision tree

```
 from sklearn import tree
 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
 import graphviz

 dt= DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1,min_samples_leaf=3, max_features=6, random_state=42)
 dt.fit(X_train, y_train)

 cols=X_train.columns

 exported=tree.export_graphviz(
     decision_tree=dt,
     out_file=None,
     feature_names=cols,
     precision=1,
     class_names=['No','Yes'],
     filled=True)

 graph=graphviz.Source(exported)
 display(graph)
```